# ASP.Net: Google Maps + store Float in MySQL --> Comma not point?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, google-maps, floating-point

I'm trying to add google maps coordinates to a float field, but I think due to my character coding (Belgium) it's not taking dots. I've set my field to "float", but it keeps changing the coordinate "54.5579" to a comma "54,5579".

What should I do to use a dot as a separator and not a comma?

Any suggestions?

Thankx!

Comment: What program is showing the comma? The MySQL shell? Some MySQL GUI? or is it the HTML output from your ASP app itself?

Comment: Can you just store the field as a string instead of a float?

Answer (score 0):

you should change 'Decimal Symbol' on your PC settings. On Windows, you can find in Region and Language, click additional Settings button.